# Indy v9 in Delphi 7 - how to extract readable text portion of TIDMessagePart.Body when ContentType is not text/plain

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy-9

I am trying to extract the readable portion of the Body.Text property of a TIDMessagePart object that is type TIDText. Something like the code below. However if ContentType of the TIDText message part is not text/plain, but is rather text/html, this fills sBody with all the HTML tags. I just want the readable text, but don't see a way to get that in the version 9 library. Am I missing something?

var
  email: TIDMessage;
  sBody: String;

...

```
for j := 0 to Pred(email.MessageParts.Count) do
begin
if email.MessageParts.Items[j] is TIdText then
begin
    sBody := TIdText(email.MessageParts.Items[j]).Body.Text;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually parse the HTML to extract the plain text you want from it.  `TIdMessage` is just an email container of data, it does not parse body content for you, other than to deal with charset conversions.  You have to parse the content yourself.

Comment: This remains true for INDY 10 and I expect to remains the same for future INDY versions.

Comment: True, there are no plans to implement a full HTML parser in Indy (there are plenty of third-party parsers available for that), however Indy 10 does have a small HTML parser in the `ParseMetaHTTPEquiv()` function of the `IdGlobalProtocols` unit, which `TIdHTTP` uses for parsing `<meta>` tags from HTML data.